# Multiplying a specific cell value based on if statement in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, lambda

So I am trying to associate a specific value ('Property Damage') with every row in my dataset but I am having some trouble with this. Specifically, I want to multiply the value in the 'MD' column for each row by a number (0.02, 0.15, etc.) if it meets the conditions specified in the for loop (e.g. if i >= 0.8062, print etc.). I have included my code below:

```
df['RAND'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=df.index.size)
dfRAND = list(df['RAND'])

def sim_1():
for i in dfRAND:
    result = []
    if i >= 0.8062:
        df['Property Damage'] = df['MD'].apply(lambda x: x * 0.02)
        print(list(val for x, val in enumerate(df['Count']) if 
                   x == dfRAND.index(i)), 'LF0', i,':', df['Property Damage'])
    elif 0.01 <= i < 0.89062:
        df['Property Damage'] = list(df['MD'].apply(lambda x: x * 0.15))
        print(list(val for x, val in enumerate(df['Count']) if 
                   x == dfRAND.index(i)),'LF1', i, ':', df['Property Damage'])
    elif 0.05 <= i < 0.01:
        df['Property Damage'] = list(df['MD'].apply(lambda x: x * 0.20))
        print(list(val for x, val in enumerate(df['Count']) if 
                   x == dfRAND.index(i)),'LF2', i,':', df['Property Damage'])
    elif 0.025 <= i < 0.05:
        df['Property Damage'] = list(df['MD'].apply(lambda x: x * 0.50))
        print(list(val for x, val in enumerate(df['Count']) if 
                   x == dfRAND.index(i)),'LF3', i,':', df['Property Damage'])
    elif 0.0125 <= i < 0.025:
        df['Property Damage'] = list(df['MD'].apply(lambda x: x * 1))
        print(list(val for x, val in enumerate(df['Count']) if 
                   x == dfRAND.index(i)),'LF4', i,':', df['Property Damage'])
    elif 0.0063 <= i < 0.0125:
        df['Property Damage'] = list(df['MD'].apply(lambda x: x * 1))
        print(list(val for x, val in enumerate(df['Count']) if 
                   x == dfRAND.index(i)),'LF5', i,':', df['Property Damage'])
```

The problem I am having at the moment is that the code prints all the 'Property Damage' values for each row. I want it to give me the 'Property Damage' value for a specific row based on whichever condition is met in the for loop.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually need it to print row by row? Or do you simply want to calculate the property damage for each row based on the multiplicative factor? If it's the latter you can do this with `numpy.select`, and then you could just print everything.

Comment: Hi @ALollz. I don't necessarily need to print it row by row but I need some way of showing the specific property damage value for each row. Is there some way I can assign the row number to each property damage in a list or something?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
my_bins = {pd.Series.max(df['RAND'])-1: 1, 
           .01: .15, 
           .0125: 1, 
           .025: .5, 
           .05: .2,
           pd.Series.max(df['RAND'])+1 : .02}
df['rand_multiplier'] = pd.cut(df['RAND'], bins = sorted(my_bins.keys()), labels = list(range(len(my_bins) - 1))).apply(lambda x: my_bins[sorted(my_bins.keys())[x]])

df.apply(lambda row: row['MD'] * row['rand_multiplier'], axis = 1)
```

I'm in a bit of a hurry so it's not the prettiest thing. Basically I created bins based on the criteria you had and created a "multiplier" column which associates each entry in `df['RAND']` with a multiplying factor. Then we can iterate over df and apply the multiplying factor to your 'MD' row.

Of course, I can't show the produced results without the 'MD' data.